# CVS command to connect extssh on non-default port

Tags: command-line, ssh, cvs

We the the way to connect to CVS server on extssh, listening at default port is:

Set the CVSROOT as following:

```
CVSROOT=:ext:<username>@<server-ip>:<repository-path>
CVS_RSH="ssh"
```

But we need to connect to CVS server with non-default port. Can you please suggest how/where to specify the port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `~/.ssh/config` to specifiy the port. check the following link for a working example

http://www.seanodonnell.com/code/?id=56